# Object Oriented PHP Login Script with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Good Day Everyone, Sorry if i made a lot of mistakes in my code but i am new to object oriented programming in `PHP` as i heard it is easily readable and organizes code.

I am trying a first project by working on a Login Script with `mysql` database.

The issue is i have written my functions but can seem to get it to work and i am not getting any errors to use to debug. Below are my codes.

I have a **database.php** file that contains most functions

```
class Database 
{
    //Database conn properties

    private $host   = 'localhost';
    private $user   = 'root';
    private $pass   = 'password';
    private $dbname = 'rtmdb';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        //Function for database connection
        //Set DSN

        $dsn = 'mysql:host='. $this->host . ';dbname'. $this->dbname;

        //Set Options include persistent connection

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        //Create new PDO Instance

        try
        {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        //@param function for executing insert, select, update

        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

        if(!$this->stmt)
        {
            echo $this->dbh->lastErrorMsg();
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        }
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) 
    {
        if(is_null($type))
        {
            switch(true)
            {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                    default;
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function clean_str($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = str_replace("'", "&#8217;", $data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function lastInsertId() 
    {
        $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function resultset()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSCO);
    }

    public function registerAdmin($fname, $lname, $oname, $uname, $email, $idnumber, $pass, $profimg, $status)
    {
        $email = $this->clean_str($email);
        $lname = $this->clean_str($lname);
        $email = $this->clean_str($oname);
        $lname = $this->clean_str($uname);
        $email = $this->clean_str($email);
        $lname = $this->clean_str($idnumber);
        $email = $this->clean_str($pass);
        $lname = $this->clean_str($profimg);
        $email = $this->clean_str($status);

        $database->query('INSERT INTO admin (fname, lname, oname, uname, email, idnumber, pass, profimg, status) VALUES(:fname, :lname, :oname, :uname, :email, :idnumber, :pass, :proofimg, :status)');

        $database->bind(':fname', $fname);
        $database->bind(':lname', $lname);
        $database->bind(':oname', $oname);
        $database->bind(':uname', $uname);
        $database->bind(':email', $email);
        $database->bind(':idnumber', $idnumber);
        $database->bind(':pass', $pass);
        $database->bind(':profimg', $profimg);
        $database->bind(':status', $status);

        $database->execute();

        if(!$database->lastInsertId())
        {
            die('Yawa Don Gas: ' . $this->dbh->lastErrorMsg());
        }
        $this->dbh->close();
    }
    public function loginAdmin($uname, $pass)
    {
        $uname = $this->clean_str($uame);
        $pass = $this->clean_str($pass);

        $database->query('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE uname = :uname AND pass = :pass');

        $database->bind(':uname', $uname);
        $database->bind(':pass', $pass);

        $results = $database->execute();
        $count = mysql_num_rows($results);

        if ($count == 1)
        {
            $rows = $database->resultset();

            foreach($rows as $row)
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $uname = $row['uname'];
                $pass = $row['pass'];
            }
            if(!isset($uname) or empty($uname))
            {
                echo 'Invalid Usernmae';
            }
            elseif(!isset($pass) or empty($pass))
            {
                echo 'Invalid Password Details';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Good';
                $set = $this->crossEncryption(ENCRYPT_KEY, 10).$id;
                setcookie('itravel', $set, time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
            }
            return;
             $this->dbh->close();
        }
    }

    public function crossEncryption($key,$length)
    {
        $characters = $key;
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['uname']))
        {
            unset($_SESSION['uname']['id']);
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
}
```

I have another **travelapis.php** file

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';

class travelapis
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->dbh = new Database;
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['uname']))
        {
            $uname = $_POST['username'];
            $pass = $_POST['password'];

            if(empty($uname) || empty($pass))
            {
                echo 'Please Fill in all Fields';
            }
            else
            {
                $this->dbh->login($uname, $pass);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then also a **login.php** file to carry out the function

```
<?php

require_once "travelapis.php";

$api = new travelapis;

$api->login();
```

This is used in the form action. For some reason i really don't understand, this doesn't seem to work. Any help would to as i need to wrap my head around OOP with `PHP`

Comment: you do not have a method `login()` in your class Database, yet you invoke it with `$this->dbh->login($uname, $pass)` - there's a `loginAdmin($uname, $pass)` method though you could invoke.

Answer (score 2):

The main issues I can spot, in no particular order:

- You don't really have an object oriented design. You have a single `Database` class that does everything. It's mostly procedural code where `Database` plays the role of `index.php`. I'd expect classes for each different concept involved: database connection, database result, administrator... And maybe some design pattern that helps with application flow (such as Model-View-Controller). What will you do when you need to implement e.g. a contact form? Add new methods to your megaclass?
- You're actively preventing proper error handling: try/catch on connection to hide the exception, `die()` in the middle of nowhere
- Methods are unpredictable: they return stuff or print to stdout (often both) without a hint.
- You have hard-coded global variables popping up from nowhere in some methods (e.g. `login()`.
- `clean_str()` has no reason to exist. If you want to keep it, give it a better name like `randomlyCorruptInputData()`.
- The database features of the class do not really have any advantage over using raw PDO. It actually makes it harder because you need to learn a new API and some PDO features become unavailable.

Comment: In other words my code is simply trash if i think i am writing OOP in PHP. Can you please direct me to a good resource?

Comment: @diagold Hey, I never said that—a code review will always find stuff, that the point :)
I'm not very familiar with learning resources but I think [PHP Delusions](https://phpdelusions.net/) has some nice articles and [PHP The right Way](https://www.phptherightway.com/) is often recommended here. However, none of these are specific to OOP. I think the important thing is that you actually understand the code you write and not just blindly copy and paste code you find in Stack Overflow (`clean_str()` is probably the case).

Answer (score 2):

In spite of all my comments below, it looks like you are learning OO.  Keep working on it.  I'm not necessarily going to find your bug for you, but rather push you forward.  After you have revised some of your code to handle the stuff below, the bug may vanish.

Something to think about in designing OO code:

- It should *not* be a thin layer.  (Else, why bother?)
- It should isolate the *implementation* end from the business-end.
- The user of the OO package should not necessarily need to understand the underlying processes.

Related to that last item:

- Consider doing `travelapis::login` from within `travelapis::__construct`.
- The caller should not have to understand prepare-bind-execute-inserted_id -- See if you can roll those together into a single call.
- Ultimately, the business-end should not even know what "tables" exist, much less how many exist.  It should say "put/get" these things into/from the database.  The package would then take care of `JOINing` tables, iterating, etc; thereby hiding the schema from the business-end.
- A select script should simply return an array of results.  Perhaps 2 versions -- an array of arrays versus an array of hashes (associative arrays).

Now for some nit-picks / bugs...

- Don't prepare twice.
- Don't stripslashes; they will already be gone (unless you erroneously doubled up on addslashes).
- Don't htmlspecialcharacters except when immediately putting in HTML.
- Consider extending PDO instead of having to always say `$this->dbh->`
- Consider adding something.  Why mimic inserted_id when you could have that returned from the query execution (for example).
- Don't bother with `mysql_num_rows` if you can just as easily do `count($rows)`
- Bug with lots of `$lname=` and `$email=`
- `clean_str` is probably totally useless.  Maybe `trim` is useful; `bind` does what mysql needs; the rest is "wrong".
- There is some code *after* a `return;`??
- `empty` checks for `isset`.

Answer (score 2):

First off, all of the previous answers have really valid and constructive comments.

I am going to assume that you are fairly new to php and OOP.  That being said this is not something that you are just going to spend a night coding and be done with.

However, you still need to write a login script from start to finish.  Then you need to evaluate your project and determine where you had problems or struggled trying to get something accomplished. Then you need to come up with a way to do it better,which is usually just a result of more simplified and structured logic.

Let's look at this from a login system point of view.  What do you have to do to log someone in.  Let's look at what it is you are truly dealing with.

Keeping it simple you will be dealing with:

- Users
- Passwords
- Validations
- Formatting
- Errors

Hint - Each one of these will end up being a class that handles those things.  Not only will the classes deal with those things, but they will deal exclusively with those categories and will be called whenever you need to do any of the above things.

I will show you a very simple example.  When you make your login form you are going to most likely have two inputs, a username and a password.  You are going to want to validate those inputs for a few things.  Like, for example, are the username and passwords blank, or long enough.

So you would make a validation class that contains functions that will check and validate those conditions.  Like so:

```
 class Validate{

    public function __construct(){

    }

//Just testing to see if it is empty.  You can add any other criteria to this that you want.
public function userName($userName){

  if(isset($userName) && $uerName){

    return TRUE;

  }else{

    return FALSE;

  }

}


//Just testing to see if it is empty.  You can add any other criteria to this that you want.
public function password($password){

  if(isset($password) && $password){

    return TRUE;

  }else{

    return FALSE;

  }

}


}
```

Now to use this just call the class Validate and pass your username and password to check if they are valid.

```
$valid = new Validate();

if(!$valid->userName($_POST['username'])){

  echo 'Sorry, There is something wrong with your username.';

}

if(!$valid->password($_POST['password'])){

  echo 'Sorry, There is something wrong with your password.';

}
```

Here are where classes are really cool.  Eventually you are going to want to validate  many different things, emails, phone numbers, names, addresses, ect..  Just add a new function to your Validate class and anytime you want to validate you just call your class and the function you require, like `valid->email()`

Even better yet, you know exactly where your code is so when you realize you need to change how something gets validated you make your edits in the class in one function and it works across your entire code base.

Like I said before, you will make an individual class for all those categories.  I think after tinkering around you will see how this is huge plus.

Another thing is not to get discouraged.  It's called learning.. You will make mistakes and you will earn from those mistakes.   The important thing is to just keep coding.

Hope this helps you.  Good luck!